# Catching error messages and states from wp cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Is it possible to catch data from wp cron? ex. I set a function to run via wp cron, I want to get the following:

- Errors/Exceptions that have been thrown inside the function if there are any so I can present it to the end user
- Success/Failure status, the function returns certain values to indicate success and failure of operation, I want to get that also from the function that is running via wp cron to display the operation status

Is this even possible? if so, any help is much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: No. WP Cron is just a task scheduler, it gives no information about the result of the cron task. That's left to the scripts. If you feel you need to do some type of error handling and you don't have access to the scripts that the cron fires, you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

To debug cron in WordPress, add your function to `sanitize_comment_cookies` hook

```
add_action('sanitize_comment_cookies', 'your-cron-function-name');
```

As `wp_cron function` gets executed in this action hook. You will see errors, if any, printed when you reload your frontend page

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out, I'll post comment as soon as I tested it